# Angular Binding field to Dynamic model modifies all values in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-track-by

So I have this code in view:

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="columnHeader in form.table[fakeForm.currentFormIndex].columns track by $index">
             <label for="">Column <%$index%></label>
             <div class="fg-line">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"             
                    placeholder="Column Header <%index%>" 
                    ng-model="form['table'][fakeForm.currentFormIndex]['columns'][$index].name"/>
             </div>
    </div>
```

This targets the 'current active' appended element. But whenever I uses this, it also modifies other appended elements with same attributes even each of those elements has unique key assigned to them.

[image: Look at the image here]

Then I'm pushing this data set with a new key.

```
'columns':[{name:'Column 1'}, {name:'Column 2'}, {name:'Column 3'}],
            'rows':[
                {
                    label:'Row 1',
                    columns:[
                        {
                            label:'Row 1 Column 1'
                        },
                        {
                            label:'Row 1 Column 2'
                        },
                        {
                            label:'Row 1 Column 3'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label:'Row 2',
                    columns:[
                        {
                            label:'Row 2 Column 1'
                        },
                        {
                            label:'Row 2 Column 2'
                        },
                        {
                            label:'Row 2 Column 3'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label:'Row 3',
                    columns:[
                        {
                            label:'Row 3 Column 1'
                        },
                        {
                            label:'Row 3 Column 2'
                        },
                        {
                            label:'Row 3 Column 3'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

so for example I have two 'table' key, it will look like

```
table:{
0:....
1:....
}
```

Comment: update with your json please!

Comment: I dont find any json data!??